# I set the style css file as design but it does not display as the original page?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to follow some online HTML CSS course and tried to code an website like this website
https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/tryw3css_templates_band.htm#

When I tried to see the hided button Merchandise, Extras, Media 's information, I saw the Elements and I saw that the padding is 8px 16px, as you can see in this picture
[image: Picture about information of w3schools]

But when I coded like them, used their information, the block became small. Like this picture

[image: picture when I coded]

Here is some of my code

```
<div id="header">
        <ul id="nav">
            <li><a href="">HOME</a></li>
            <li><a href="">BAND</a></li>
            <li><a href="">TOUR</a></li>
            <li><a href="">CONTACT</a></li>
            <li>
                <a href="">MORE
            <ul class="subnav">
                <li><a href="">Merchandise</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Extras</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Media</a></li>
            </ul>        
                </a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

My styles.css file is here

```
#nav li {
position: relative;
}

#nav > li {
display: inline-block;
}

#nav li a {
text-decoration: none;
line-height: 46px;
padding: 0 24px;
display: block;
}

#nav li:hover .subnav {
display: block;
}

#nav .subnav {
/*display: none;*/
position: absolute;
background-color: #fff;
top :100%;
left :0;
}

#nav .subnav a {
color: #000;
padding: 0 16px;
}
```

My question is, why I set padding exactly they display but it became fell in ?
Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Try using side of padding in particular, like padding-right or padding-left, and tell me if that workds

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, your question is why the widths of your <li> elements are shorter than the example.

In short, add **min-width: 160px;** under your **#nav .subnav a** CSS selector.

```css
#nav .subnav a {
    min-width: 160px;
    color: #000;
    padding: 0 16px;
}
```

Explanation:
As in your screenshot, the original example has CSS "width: 100%" which I believe you've tried but didn't work as expected. In fact, that 100% means it will follow the father <div> width (shown in following screenshot), which is set to "min-width: 160px;". Instead of following the exact structure, you may want to keep it simple, so just add "min-width" to <a>!

[CSS of example page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3W9zZ.png)

Comment: Greate answer! But **min-width** is not needed at all.

Comment: @AmirrezaAmini I tried Yue 's answer and min-width is still needed bro.